# Debugging a plugin for Webstorm from IDEA

Tags: java, debugging, plugins, intellij-idea, webstorm

I'm working with a plugin for Jetbrain's Webstorm, and we're using IntelliJ IDEA as our IDE for the project; however unfortunately no one has touched this project in a while and remembers how to help the new guy out ;)

Right now I can deploy the .jar file and copy it into Webstorm's plugin directory. I can essentially test by doing that, but I'd like to be able to step through - which is my question to you, since I have no idea what the process is to debug this.

I'm assuming I need to attach IDEA to the process, but I can't figure out where to do so - or if I need to configure Webstorm for anything as well.

Help would be greatly appreciated - thanks!

**Edit: bin/Webstorm.exe.vmoptions** file

```
-Xms32m
-Xmx500m
-XX:MaxPermSize=150m
-ea
-Didea.platform.prefix=WebStorm
-Xdebug -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=n,address=5005
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to debug the code of plug-in that runs in WebStorm you need to use **Remote** debug configuration in IntelliJ IDEA. Copy the suggested JVM options and place them in `bin\webstorm.exe.vmoptions` file, start WebStorm, execute the Debug configuration in IntelliJ IDEA to connect to the WebStorm instance and step through the code of the plug-in.

You can also debug this plug-in directly in IntelliJ IDEA using the **Plugin** Run/Debug configuration type.

Comment: Thanks for your response! I edited the .vmoptions as you said (Copied current contents above); however after starting up Webstorm I go to debug, the option is grayed out within IntelliJ IDEA. Also - if the Plugin Run/Debug Config type is any easier, I'd be happy to try that - but I'm unsure exactly what to do (I see the Plugin section in IDEA's Debug dialog, but not sure what to add to it)

Comment: What option is grayed out? You need to create the new Debug configuration of Remote type, then select it in the drop-down in IntelliJ IDEA, then press the Debug button on the right. Same for the Plugin Run/Debug configuration type. Please refer to help for details: http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/running-and-debugging-2.html.

Comment: Ah, gotchya - I was working with the defaults settings, not creating a new one. Now I have the option to debug; but I can't seem to connect as I receive the error: " Error running Unnamed: Unable to open debugger port: java.new.ConnectException "Connection refused: connect" "

I use client/server programs on this computer and have never had any requests to open ports from a firewall, just as an FYI. I'll double check Windows FW real quick though.

Comment: Verify with TcpView that WebStorm is really running in Debug mode and listens on the specified port (5005), also check that this port is not used by some other application.

Comment: Checked with TcpView and it seems no other applications are using the port; but neither is Webstorm - it's only processes are listening, so I'm assuming that it is not running in Debug mode - any idea why this would be? (I'm just opening it as I normally would)

Comment: Maybe you've modified vmoptions file incorrectly, it should have no spaces, one option per line.

Comment: Well now I feel silly. The dialog stated I could copy and paste that command into .vmoptions - I thought that second command was just a parameter for the first; I moved it to the second line and everything works great now. Thank you so much!